# Determine which values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ cause the following vectors to be a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am working on the following problem.

Suppose that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis of a real vector space $V$.
For which values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ a basis of $V$, where $w_+ = v_1 + v_2$ and $w_\lambda = v_1 - \lambda v_2$?

My thought process so far has been as follows:

I think that it is clear that $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ is a basis of $V$ when $\lambda = 1$.

I then note that, for $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ to be a basis of $V$, $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ must be linearly independent.

Then I consider when $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ are not linearly independent.
This occurs when $\alpha v_1 + \alpha v_2 = v_1 - \lambda v_2,$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  $(*)$
That is, $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ are linearly dependent when $w_\lambda$ can be obtained from a scalar multiple of $w_+$ (vice versa).
I think that the only case in which $(*)$ holds is when $\lambda = -1.$
Therefore, I conclude that $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ is a basis for $V \space \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus\{-1\}$.
Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: It's whenever the determinant of the coefficient matrix for $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ is not $0$, i.e. $det\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -\lambda \end{pmatrix} \neq 0$.

Comment: Why is this, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to write every element $\alpha \in V$ as a linear combination of $w_+$ and $w_{\lambda}$:

$$
\alpha=aw_++bw_{\lambda}=a(v_1+v_2)+b(v_1-\lambda v_2),
$$

so that $\alpha=(a+b)v_1+(a-b\lambda)v_2$. Since $v_1,v_2$ is a basis, we also have $\alpha=cv_1+dv_2$, which implies that $a+b=c$ and $a-b\lambda =d$. What can you conclude about $\lambda$?

Comment: Why do I 'need to be able to write every element $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ as a linear combination of $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$'?  Is it because the phrase '$V$ is a real vector space' means that $V = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what I can conclude about $\lambda$.  Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean $\alpha \in V$. I will correct it now. Being able to write it as a linear combination is criteria for being a basis. $w_+$ and $w_{\lambda}$ have to span $V$.

Comment: Also, you say that $\lambda$ can equal $-1$, but it cannot. In this case, $w_+=w_{\lambda}$, which is not allowed since they have to be linearly independent.

Comment: I have edited my question.  I didn't mean to say that $\lambda$ can equal $-1$.  What I meant was that, when $\lambda = -1$, then $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

They give you the transformation from $\{v_1, v_2\}$ to $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\
1 & -\lambda \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\
v_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} w_+ \\
w_\lambda \end{pmatrix}
$$

Now the question is, can we transform the *other* way, from $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ to $\{v_1, v_2\}$?  Using matrix multiplication this is simple:

$$
 \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\
v_2\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\
1 & -\lambda \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \times\begin{pmatrix} w_+ \\
w_\lambda \end{pmatrix}
$$

*However*, the inverse of the matrix doesn't exist when its determinant is $0$:

$$
1*(-\lambda) - 1*1 = -\lambda - 1 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda = -1
$$

Therefore this inverse transformation exists for every $\lambda \neq -1$.  We could find the exact transformation using the definition of the [inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix](http://www.mathwords.com/i/inverse_of_a_matrix.htm) (but this isn't necessary to answer the question of what values of $\lambda$ span $V$/have an inverse mapping from $\{w_+, w_\lambda\}$ to $\{v_1, v_2\}$).

Comment: So, you have shown which values of $\lambda$ cause $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ to span $V$.  However, we must also consider when $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ are linearly independent.  This is what I tried to do in my question.  Was my thought process regarding the linear independence/dependence of $w_+$ and $w_\lambda$ correct?

Comment: @CKKOY Spanning $V$ and being linearly independent mean essentially the same thing.  Since $V$ is two dimensional then two linearly independent vectors will span $V$ and vice versa any two vectors which span $V$ are linearly independent.  You may be thinking of [orthogonality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Euclidean_vector_spaces)--which is not necessary to be basis vectors.

Comment: @CKKOY And yes, your original conclusion was correct although it may be more difficult to reason through something like that if the dimensions were higher--in that case using matrices and understanding what they mean will help you solve much more difficult problems.